# Setting update and insert property in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, properties, insert

In the hibernate HBM file, what is the purpose of setting the following properties?

```
update = "false"
insert = "false"
```

What purpose do they serve? What difference do they make to the performance? When should we use them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e6525):

> update, insert (optional - defaults to true): specifies that the
>   mapped columns should be included in SQL UPDATE and/or INSERT
>   statements. Setting both to false allows a pure "derived" property
>   whose value is initialized from some other property that maps to the
>   same column(s), or by a trigger or other application.

Comment: Whats the advantage of using it?

Comment: There is no advantage. You set update=false if you don't want the column to be updated (for example, if it's updated by a trigger or another column). And you set insert to false if you don't want the column to be inserted (for example, if it's initialized by a trigger or another column). In 99% of the cases, leave it to its default value: true.

Comment: How do i do this for a set (child)?

Answer (score 11):

Use update="false", insert="false" when the property is calculated/derived, or when the database or triggers are responsible for inserting/ or updating the value.

For example, if the DB would automatically generate a value on INSERT that you want to use, then specify insert="false" so Hibernate won't include the property in INSERT statements.

Another example, would be a calculated/derived property via SQL formula:  You could, for example, retrieve a sum of order-totals for each customer. Eg:

```
<property name="totalOrders" insert="false" update="false">
  <formula>(select sum(ORDER.TOTAL) from ORDER where ORDER.FK_CUSTOMER=ID)</formula>
</property>
```

In this case we set insert="false", update="false" since this is clearly a derived result, and we can't update it directly.

Performance? It's not about performance -- it's about what your database mapping requires.

Comment: How can i do this for a set?