# Why many-to-one bidirectional association requires update and insert set to false

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

The [Hibernate document](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch08.html#assoc-bidirectional-m21) says that if I want to use a list then I need to set the properties for `update="false" and insert="false"`.

Please let me know why these attributes are needed and how is this useful?

> If you use a List, or other indexed collection, set the key column of
>   the foreign key to not null. Hibernate will manage the association
>   from the collections side to maintain the index of each element,
>   making the other side virtually inverse by setting update="false" and
>   insert="false":

```
<class name="Person">
   <id name="id"/>
   ...
   <many-to-one name="address"
      column="addressId"
      not-null="true"
      insert="false"
      update="false"/>
</class>

<class name="Address">
   <id name="id"/>
   ...
   <list name="people">
      <key column="addressId" not-null="true"/>
      <list-index column="peopleIdx"/>
      <one-to-many class="Person"/>
   </list>
</class>
```

I have also gone through this post [Setting update and insert property in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639195/setting-update-and-insert-property-in-hibernate), but when I wrote a simple program to create and save my Person and Address objects I can see that addressId property is inserted and updated by hibernate itself:

```
Hibernate: insert into Address (addressId) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into person1 (addressId, peopleId, personId) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into person1 (addressId, peopleId, personId) values (?, ?, ?)

09:19:08,526 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1205 - Inserting collection: [partc.onetomany1.Address.people#156]
Hibernate: update person1 set addressId=?, peopleId=? where personId=?
Hibernate: update person1 set addressId=?, peopleId=? where personId=?
```

But as per comments given by [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) and [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768795/thomas-w), this should not happen. Please let me know if I misunderstood the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the example from the Hibernate Documentation. And i can try to help as much as i can.

```
@Entity
public class Troop {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="troop")
    public Set<Soldier> getSoldiers() {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Soldier {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_id")
    public Troop getTroop() {
    ...
}
```

Your table structure in this case would be

```
**Troop**
Troop_id | Troop_desc
T1       | Troop 1
T2       | Troop 2

**Soldier**
Soldier_Id | Troop_Id | Soldier_Name
S1         | T1       | XYZ
S2         | T2       | PQR
```

**Consider in the above situation you need to add a Soldier the function calls would be

1) create the Soldier with the Troop and save it on the Soldier table.**

**Consider this to be managed from the Troop entity, where you would have to do the following transactions

1) you append the soldier to the soldiers collection in the Troop entity

2) create the soldier.

3) update the Troop entity too.**

So, that is why you would have an insert and an update in the second condition where you have a @OneToMany as the managing side.

Now, coming back to why the documentation mentions that the @ManytoOne JoinColumn should be insertable=false, updateable = false is because in the second scenario, where (@OneToMany side of the relation is the managing side) you would update the Soldier by updating the Troop entity.

I think it ties back to how you design your application on what should be the relation which you want to manage and from where.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. I have few doubts here. In the example you gave, the name of the join column you mentioned is `troop_fk`, but I see `troop_id` as foreign key in `Soldier` table, are they same? Next is in the 3 points you mentioned for second scenario, I understand that a new record will be inserted into `Soldier` table and then an `update` query is run to update the foreign key which is `troop_id` in this case. So is my understanding is correct? Where as in 1st scenario there will be a single insert query to save the soldier record.

Comment: Yes, sorry about the confusion. It is supposed to be troop_id. Yes an excess update happens with the second approach for the troop entity.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I have another doubt here, since hibernate definitely has to execute an insert query in bothe scenarios to save the Soldier entity then what does `insert="false"` means?